# removeChild when object leaves the stage. Code works but gives Error #2025 message

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I'm receiving an error (Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.) while trying to remove an object once it leaves the stage.

The object spawns off stage on the right (stage.width - (enemy.width * -0.5)), moves to the left, and then removes when the object reaches a point. I want this point to be off stage on the left, when the object has fully left the stage (enemy.width * -0.5), but any time I use a value less than 0, I receive the error message, either once at the start or infinitely depending on how I write the code. The code is functional with the error, but I still want it gone. If I use a value of 0 as the point to remove the object, the code runs without error, but the registration point needs to be in the center of the objects, and this removes the object before it has fully left the stage. I'm posting all of the code I believe is relevant to the issue.

```
var enemyType:Array = [Enemy1, Enemy2, Enemy3, Enemy4, Enemy5];
var enemyTypeRandomNumber:int = Math.random() * (enemyType.length);
var enemy = new enemyType[enemyTypeRandomNumber];

public function checkEveryFrame(event:Event):void
{
    // remove enemy if it leaves the stage
    //if (enemy.x <= enemy.width * -0.5) // Works but spits out error message every frame.
    //if (enemy.x == enemy.width * -0.5)// Works but gives error only once at the start.
    if (enemy.x == 0) // works but removes the enemy object when it is only half off the screen.
    {
            removeChild (enemy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29953934/469755) does a good job of answering your question.

I'd add that it's also generally good practice to verify that an object is on the display list before attempting to remove it:

```
if(this.contains(enemy)){
    this.removeChild(enemy);
}
```

This will prevent an error if you accidentally try to remove an object twice, but I generally think of this as a failsafe after I've already cleaned up the object and its listeners as Null suggests.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you use descriptive names like `checkEveryFrame`.
So this is executed repeatedly, every frame.

And this is the answer.

1. Your code runs for the first time.
2. The condition is true.
3. It removes the enemy.
4. Your code runs again.
5. The condition is (still) true.
6. It removes the enemy **again**, but failing this time, because it
   already removed the enemy the first time.

To solve this, either remove the listener for the event.
Or store your enemy in an array.
When removing it from the display list, remove it from the array as well.

In your function, iterate over the array (which may or may not have 1 element, or more) and check the condition on all elements.